# Opposite idiom for putting my foot down

Tags: phrases, idioms, phrase-requests, american-english

I got stumped when trying to write the opposite of "putting my foot down".
 As an example i'll give some context. I said: "In these instances I always put my foot down, but you make me **X**", where **X** should be the opposite, i.e. something like "lift my foot back up" or "act in a way contrary to my usual firm behavior in these situations"...

What should **X** be? (it does not have to be an idiom, but one would be preferable)

Comment: "give you leeway": http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leeway

Comment: "step on the gas"...

Comment: @AllInOne ~ 'step on the gas' is used in the context of going faster/hurrying up. It has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @V0ight I think his comment was tongue in cheek - something about speeding ahead combined with the literal action of putting one's foot down on the pedal to accelerate.

Comment: @Rome_Leader ~ my tongue-in-cheek detector must be on the fritz then

Comment: The opposite of ‘putting my foot down’? ***Raising my hand***, obviously. ;-)

Comment: I would say you should ease up on the gas to give yourself time to think about it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet How 'bout *throw up my hands*?

Comment: @StoneyB Even better!

Comment: It's never a good idea to put your foot down, if you haven't a leg to stand on! That's if you really want to mix your metaphors!

Comment: @StoneyB, you should make that an answer.

Comment: "go easy on you"; "spare the rod (and spoil you/the child)"; "turn a blind eye (to your antics/misbehavior/rule-breaking)."

Comment: Given your context where you're already using one particular idiom, do you really need another for the opposite? You could simply say "In these instances I always put my foot down, but this time, I will make an exception." which is easier to understand for someone that may not be able to see immediately whether the two idioms are truly opposites. Of course, that only works in this specific instance. "I will make an exception" by itself doesn't work when someone doesn't know your norms.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Aside from No More Secrets' excellent suggestion, "cut someone some slack," there is "**let it slide**," which means not to oppose something that may be objectionable but that (apparently) is not intolerable. Christine Ammer, *The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms* (1997) discusses "let slide" in an entry for "let ride":

> **let ride** Also **let slide**. Allow something to be ignored or to take or continue its natural course. For example, *Bill disagreed with Mary's description, but he let it ride*, or *He had a way of letting things slide*. The first term, alluding to things moving along as though they were riding a horse or vehicle, dates from the early 1900s; the variant, using slide in the sense of "pass by," dates from the late 1500s.

I find Ammer's decision to equate "let slide" with "let ride" somewhat unsatisfactory. To me, the essential image of "let slide" is "let go downhill"—that is, allow to happen for the worse—which "let ride" doesn't suggest at all. Usually, when you let something slide, you are allowing something below the normal standard to occur, often because you aren't willing to put your foot down about upholding or enforcing the standard in question.

Other expressions that may work in certain circumstances are "**fall asleep at the switch**," which applies to cases where a failure to put one's foot down can have calamitous results (the original reference is to a railroad switchman in charge of switching tracks that trains run on), and "**let the inmates run the asylum**," which refers to ceding authority to individuals who need supervision but are instead left to supervise themselves (the reference is to an insane asylum).

Comment: Another one, related in meaning to "let it slide", might be "look the other way"

Comment: Going downhill gives an idea of a worsening situation, like continual tumbling, which is not what this idiom expresses. Instead I believe it more specifically refers to a lack of resistance and letting something easily evade notice. Compare this with the [slip by](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/slip+by) idiom, also found in the American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms and [Noah Webster's entry for the word slide in the American Dictionary of the English language](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336260/opposite-idiom-for-putting-my-foot-down), especially the 5th & 6th definitions.

Answer (score 23):

["Cut someone some slack"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cut-someone-some-slack)

> *informal* Allow someone some leeway in their conduct  -- Oxford Dictionaries

["Ease up on someone"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ease%20up%20on)

> to treat (someone) in a less harsh or demanding way  -- Merriam-Webster

Answer (score 16):

If you never put your foot down, you could be acting as a [doormat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doormat) (figurative meaning) and letting someone [walk all over you](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/walk_all_over).

Probably not what you wanted but I couldn't resist the foot-related opposite :).  EDIT: all those comments and no-one thought of it :).

Comment: Big +1. "but for you, I let you walk all over *me*"

Comment: @Otheus Or even just "but I let you walk all over me."

Comment: I like this, especially because it keeps the foot metaphor going.

Answer (score 10):

To *put your foot down* is to insist on having your way in a situation where you wouldn't otherwise. It illustrates the act of taking a stance to resist some force being exerted on your body by planting your feet firmly.

You could say the opposite action would be *relenting* and letting whatever may happen, happen.

> I wanted to put my foot down, but her argument convinced me to relent.

Similar idioms include:

- *going with the flow*, which literally describes the act of allowing the forces of a river or wave you're standing in to move you rather than fighting to remain stationary.

  > I normally have to put my foot down when I'm uncomfortable, but today I decided to *go with the flow*.
- *giving in*, which describes collapsing under the force of weight.

  > I'd put my foot down, but I had to *give in* when I saw that look in your eye.
- *caving in* or *caving*, which also describes collapsing under weight.

  > I'd have put my foot down, but my hunger made me *cave* to his will.

Answer (score 7):

While the answers are good suggestions, I would like to propose **roll over** as the ideal idiom to use as it implies that the person is totally complicit in the request as opposed to putting their foot down, or protesting after letting something go and/or not noticing the thing that was happening.

> **Roll Over**
>
> To consent or comply passively or without protest; acquiesce: "You shouldn't just roll over and give in when your kids want something!"

To paraphrase your sample sentence:

> " I always put my foot down, but this time you got me to roll over."

Answer (score 7):

I saw this was already mentioned as a comment, but I believe it is the best answer. As was also mentioned already, to "`put your foot down`" is to assert your authority on a matter to have your way after another's insistence. The complete opposite is to

```
"Throw your hands up"
```

which means to "give up and yield to the insistence of another, allowing them to have their way". It is also the best answer because of the analogical imagery of "foot" "down" vs "hands" "up".

Answer (score 6):

To me the obvious opposite is *letting up*. To *let up* is to relax or remove a condition or constraint.

"*Hey! **Let up on the gas** a bit, would you please?*"

> **Verb:** let up
>
> Become less in amount or intensity
>
> "The rain let up after a few hours";
>
> - abate, slack off, slack, die away   Reduce pressure or intensity "he let up the gas pedal and the car slowed down";
> - ease up, ease off
>
> *Derived forms:* letups, lets up, letting up, let up
>
> *Type of:* alter, break, change, decrease, diminish, fall, intermission,
> interruption, lessen, modify, pause, suspension

---

> **Noun:** letup  'let,úp
>
> A pause during which things are calm or
> activities are diminished
>
> "there was never a letup in the noise";
>
> - lull

-- [WordWeb Online](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=let+up)

Comment: Or 'relent', as a single word replacement

Comment: @Gus: If you say so. But sorry, I don't recognize that use of *relent*.

Answer (score 6):

Your sentence makes me think of **back down**.

> withdraw a claim or assertion in the face of opposition — New Oxford American Dictionary

Backing down is very nearly the opposite of putting one's foot down; it means letting the other person win the argument as opposed to insisting on your own way. Even the metaphors are opposite: putting your foot down means taking a firm stand and not moving or backing down. As an alternative, **yield** describes exactly what you mean.

> give way to arguments, demands, or pressure — New Oxford American Dictionary

Comment: Welcome to ELU Adding definitions of these words and links would improve this answer.

Answer (score 5):

"Turn a blind eye" is a good opposite.

> Turning a blind eye is an idiom describing the ignoring of undesirable 
>   information.
>   [-Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turning_a_blind_eye)

If "putting your foot down" is a response to reprehensible behavior of some sort, "turning a blind eye" would be quite the opposite.

"Rather than putting my foot down and demanding change to the company's pollution policy, I turned a blind eye to the toxic waste being dumped into the river."

Answer (score 2):

Other suggestions...

...have a 'laissez faire' attitude - ok it's french, but it means let it happen and it is used in english as an idiom.

...being a bit wet about something.

...giving someone enough rope to hang themselves - this is not putting your foot down but letting someone get on with something even when it is clear that they are going to 'mess up'.

these are all opposite of 'putting your foot down', but don't really fit with **X** in your question. To be honest your sentence doesn't quite sound right... I would like to suggest some alternatives....

- Normally I always put my foot down, in your case I'll make an exception.
- In these situations I always put my foot down, but you can have enough rope to hang yourself if you really want...

Answer (score 2):

In keeping with the foot theme, an idiom you could use is "bring to heel," meaning to obey or conform to what's being said or told to that person.

> If you bring someone to heel, you make them obey you. ('Call someone to heel' is also used.)

From http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/bring+someone+to+heel.html

To use your example, "In these instances I always put my foot down, but you bring me to heel."

Answer (score 1):

"... but you turn me into a pushover."

Says [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pushover):

> 1. Someone who is easily swayed or influenced to change his/her mind or comply.
>
> *I'm a pushover when it comes to buying new kitchen gadgets.*
>
> 2. Someone who lets himself be picked or bullied on without defending or stand up for him/herself.

Answer (score 1):

As 'put my foot down' is basically 'don't allow it', I'd say that you have two options -- either 'turn a blind eye' (as Sliew mentioned), which is 'I'll overlook that you're not following the rules', but for a specific 'allow', I'd go with **give my blessing**.

[From Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/blessing):

> Outside a religious context, blessings are less formal. "I give you my blessing" simply means "It's OK with me." People give their blessings to ideas and actions when they agree with them. Giving a blessing is often the same as giving permission.

Answer (score 0):

Let's be clear; unless one is driving a motor car, *putting one's foot down* is actually putting one's foot in a very particular place, namely on soneone's neck as a choke hold.

SO if you wish to express the opposite effect, that is simply *taking one's foot off their necks*.

Comment: I think putting one's foot down is about taking a stand, perhaps a fighting stance.

Comment: Pieter, do you have evidence for this? The earliest mention that I can find (in the specific sense of saying "no") has nothing to do with choke holds, it's far more literal in the sense of *standing your ground*. From 1867 in [The Sword and the Trowel](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=HyUEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA342&dq=%22put+your+foot+down%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_ieSxkfzNAhWJFpQKHcyJDYcQ6AEINzAF#v=onepage&q=%22put%20your%20foot%20down%22&f=false): "Put your foot down where you mean to stand, and let no man move you from the right. Learn to say, 'No,' ..."

Answer (score 0):

Being a **soft touch**.

Definition:

> A person who is easily influenced, duped, or imposed upon.

Sample sentence:

> A soft touch for anybody with a sob story.

Your sentence becomes:

> In these instances I always put my foot down, but you make me a soft touch.

Source: [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/soft-touch)